# Add item to state after updating in API call using NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular9

I am using NGRX/Entity with Angular 9 and I have the entities:

```
export interface Post {
  id: number;
  content: string;
  title: string;
  tags: Tag[];
} 

export interface Tag {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

And the reducer is something like:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<Post> { }

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Post> = createEntityAdapter<Post>();

export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState();

const postReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(PostActions.updatePost, (state, { post }) => {
    return adapter.updateOne(post, state)
  })
```

When updating a post the API accepts a model different from when getting:

```
export interface PostUpdateModel {
  id: number;
  content: string;
  title: string;
  tagsIds: number[];
}
```

My idea would be to have an Effect that accepts a PostUpdateModel and sends it to the API which returns a Post and then call updateOne.

Does this make sense? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this makes sense.
Another way at looking at it is to send the whole `Post` object to the effect and let the effect map it to a request object.

Also, at the moment a collection of tags is stored for each post. This can be harder to maintain in more complex scenarios because this data is duplicated, [normaling state](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/normalizing-state) can offer a solution to tackle this problem (if you have it).

Comment: I have been reading about normalising state and normalizr ... By using this approach shouldn't I use a global state instead of a state per page? Imagine I have two pages, one displays recent posts with tags and the second top posts without tags. But both would use the global state where Posts and Tags entities exist in a normalised state. Or should I keep having a specific state per page?

Comment: You will have 1 global state, and multiple selectors that compose a "viewmodel" for your pages.